# How to display banners in live wallpaper preview?

Tags: android, admob, ads, live-wallpaper, banner

I am working on a live wallpaper and I need to display a banner on top of the preview screen. I have tried several solutions, but none seems to work. I found a similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7439885/how-do-i-put-an-ads-banner-in-the-preview-screen-for-a-live-wallpaper/20818462?noredirect=1#comment31217488_20818462) but I think the solution that was proposed there was more to display banners in the settings screen.

The toolkit I am using (which seems to be a wrapper of [AdMob](http://www.google.com/ads/admob/)) has been built for standard android applications (not live wallpapers), and it needs an activity to be able to display the banner.

So my questions is:

- is there a way to display an ad in a live wallpaper in preview mode?
- otherwise, is there a way to include an activity inside the preview of live wallpaper or use the preview mode itself as an activity?

Thanks for your answer.