# Ads in live wallpaper settings not working

Tags: android, settings, admob, ads, live-wallpaper

I am trying to have ads banner in settings page of live wallpaper , but despite my numerous attempts cant add the ads. I followed many tutorials but neither works. Please suggest me what i am doing wrong.

I followed this tutorial

http://irinaramazova.blogspot.in/2011/09/add-admob-adview-to-preferenceactivity.html

and I also saw this usefull

[How do I put an admob adview in the settings screen for a live wallpaper?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4003701/how-do-i-put-an-admob-adview-in-the-settings-screen-for-a-live-wallpaper)

neither works. 
My code is as follows

My Admobpreference class

```
public class AdmobPreference extends Preference
{

public AdmobPreference(Context context) {
    super(context, null);
}

public AdmobPreference(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);
}

@Override
protected View onCreateView(ViewGroup parent) {
        //override here to return the admob ad instead of a regular preference display
    LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) getContext().getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    return inflater.inflate(R.layout.admob_preference, null);
}

}
```

admobpreference.xml file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:myapp="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/com.djcharon.valentinesday"
xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/lib/com.google.ads"
android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="fill_parent"
>

<com.google.ads.adview android:id="@+id/adView" android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content" ads:adunitid="myid" ads:adsize="BANNER"  >      
</com.google.ads.adview>
</LinearLayout>
```

my activity_preference.xml file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<PreferenceScreen xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >

  <com.djcharon.valentinesday.AdmobPreference android:key="adView" />
<CheckBoxPreference android:key="touch" android:title="Enable Touch" android:defaultValue="true"></CheckBoxPreference>


<ListPreference  android:key="kiss" android:title="Wallpaper" android:summary="Select the Wallpaper" android:defaultValue="Background 1" android:entries="@array/listKissSound" android:entryValues="@array/listKissSound" ></ListPreference>
<ListPreference  android:key="heartLife" android:title="Particle life" android:summary="The Particle lifecicle." android:defaultValue="20" android:entries="@array/listLifeCicle" android:entryValues="@array/listLifeCicle" ></ListPreference>

</PreferenceScreen>
```

I added activity in my manifest

```
 <activity android:name="com.google.ads.AdActivity"

          android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenLayout|uiMode|screenSize|smallestScreenSize">
     </activity>
```

I get an error

error inflating com.google.ads.adView

Comment: Have you added the jar file of the google ads ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5819369/error-no-resource-identifier-found-for-attribute-adsize-in-package-com-googl and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5613398/admob-missing-required-xml-attribute-adunitid

Comment: i added the jar and I also looked into the two links given above, saying mine is the duplicate. When i used the suggestion in the above links, the errors dissapear but then my app crashes when settings button is pressed.

Comment: please change your xml and preferences activity as per my example.

Answer (score 0):

Now Admob used `google-playstore service` library.

Please refer below **link.**

https://developers.google.com/mobile-ads-sdk/docs/admob/fundamentals

Comment: That link is useless given the fact that it does not specify how to add an adview strictly through xml without the use of an activity.

Comment: @Steve check https://developers.google.com/mobile-ads-sdk/docs/admob/fundamentals#play-xml with subsection 
Create your banner in XML

Comment: Thank you but I've tried that already. That specifies that an activity needs to be present for the xml banner to work. Where as the previous method did not. For someone like me though, having google play services utilized in your app makes it impossible to use the previous google ads lib for the previous method. Conflicts with the new lib.